# Cannot install package subversion from deb file

Tags: 12.04, package-management, software-installation

On Ubunut 12 VM, I am trying to install svn 1.7 taken from wandisco website. I am using the deb installation file and command line. I get a dependency error:

```
john@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i subversion_1.7.9-1+WANdisco_i386.deb;
Selecting previously unselected package subversion.
(Reading database ... 146413 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking subversion (from subversion_1.7.9-1+WANdisco_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of subversion:
 subversion depends on libsvn1 (= 1.7.9-1+WANdisco); however:
  Package libsvn1 is not installed.
 subversion depends on libapr1 (>= 1.2.7); however:
  Package libapr1 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing subversion (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 subversion
```

The following commands do not work.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends *.deb
```

Avoid the above one.

```
sudo dpkg -i downloaded_package.deb
sudo apt-get -f install

Use gebi GUI package installer.
```

All buttons are disabled in GUI. Don't know why.

```
You can insall it using apt-get install package_name. But first move your 
deb file to /var/cache/apt/archives/ directory. After executing this command,
it will automatically download its dependency.
```

How do I make this work?

PS - I'd rather take my malware infested windows :) At least you can get things done.

Comment: Why not just do `sudo apt-get install subversion`?

Comment: You need to get the `libsvn1` and any other related packages from the wandisco website.

Comment: @muru - could not find it in wandisco, but found it in http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/libsvn1/download/. Now, it says that libapr1 is missing. :)

Comment: You're just setting yourself for a mess if you download arbitrary packages. That link is for 10.04.

Comment: @muru - my bad. I just downloaded the one for 12, i.e precise pangolin (fancy names!) - http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libsvn1. This one also does not work.

Comment: I doubt that would work either (if it did, it would have worked when you did `apt-get install -f`.

Comment: why are you downloading deb files for your distro! learn how to use apt-get

Answer (score 0):

You can try `gdebi`. `gdebi` will install a `.deb` package resolving all it dependencies i.e. it will install the package along with all dependencies from a `.deb` file provided that the dependencies are satisfiable by packages from the repositories mentioned in the source lists. First install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Now for your `.deb` file, from the downloaded directory run:

```
sudo gdebi subversion_1.7.9-1+WANdisco_i386.deb
```

This will install the package satisfying all dependencies.

If you want to explore more, `gdebi` also has a nice feature that will give you a `apt-get install` compatible line from the `.deb` file containing all dependencies:

```
sudo gdebi --apt-line subversion_1.7.9-1+WANdisco_i386.deb
```

Check [`man gdebi`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/gdebi.1.html) for more info.

Need to mention that, you can also just run `xdg-open pacakge.deb` to open it via the software center that will do all the tasks `gdebi` would do i.e. software center will install the pacakge satisfying all the dependencies. (Thanks "muru" for the info).

Comment: You don't need `gdebi` anymore. The Software Centre can handle dependencies. Just double click on the package, or do `xdg-open foo.deb`. In this particular case, `sudo apt-get install -f` is probably all that's needed.

Comment: Thanks. The last command gives an error - `Dependency is not satisfiable: libsvn1 (= 1.7.9-1+WANdisco)`

Comment: @muru: `sudo apt-get install -f` should do it..just mentioning another way..

Comment: I'm just mentioning that the "other way" is handled by the Software Centre now,

Comment: @heemayl - did the install -f thing. Then, I did this - `john@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i libsvn1_1.6.6dfsg-2ubuntu1.3_i386.deb
(Reading database ... 146470 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libsvn1 1.6.6dfsg-2ubuntu1.3 (using libsvn1_1.6.6dfsg-2ubuntu1.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libsvn1 ...
Setting up libsvn1 (1.6.6dfsg-2ubuntu1.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place` FAILED.

Comment: @muru: Answer modified..

Comment: or right click the deb package and open with ubuntu software center. That does not work though. Same old error - libsvn1 dependency is not present.

Comment: @stack1: As official repos cant help you you need to satisfy the dependency yourself..search for the needed `libsvn1` package and install it manually..

Comment: @stack1: Found it.. install libsvn1: http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/svn17/binary-i386/libsvn1_1.7.9-1%2bWANdisco_i386.deb